# SELECT * but also use CAST()

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I'm trying to select all fields for a number of rows from my MySQL table. One of my fields is called `publication_date` and it stores a string that represents a day that specific row is to be published on our website. It's stored in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

I know I can cast that field to a `DATE` data type using CAST, but I'm not sure how to also grab the other fields' data.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 5):

Just add that column to your `SELECT` clause in addition to the `*`. Make sure to give it an alias so you can differentiate it from the regular datetime field.

```
SELECT *
     , CAST(datefield AS date) AS aliasname
  FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
Select *,cast(publication_date as char) as newPublicationdate from tableName
```

Or if your table do not have lots of column it is much better to type it all

```
   Select column1,column2,cast(publication_date as char) as publication_date from tableName
```

Regards